# Javascript request across domains

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a request across domains like that:

```
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src',"http://www.example.com/wordpress/register/?callback=callbackF&ver=2.5&url="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href));
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("id", "spark_grazit_script");
    document.getElementById("spark_static_widget").parentNode.appendChild(script);
```

As the script will be created, it will be appended to the div that i have and there will be a request. At the end of the request:

```
   function callbackF(data){
            console.log('Response has finished'+data);
        }
```

That function should be triggered at the end of the request. All I want is to get the callback function called.

I dont get a cross domain error. But I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want without resorting to html5 or jsonp. Can I somehow still get a response with ajax?

**UPDATE:**
The response is a simple json object

This is the response:

```
{ "userid":"24645", "token":"40A164ECA4DE4A4F", "script":"<script type='text/javascript'>var dbnwid=16211; var dbnpid=23113; var dbnwebid=19459; var dbnlayout=21; var dbncolor='#000000'; var dbntitlefontsize='14'; var dbnbgcolortype=1; var dbnheader='You might enjoy reading:'; var dbnremindercolor=2; var dbn_protocol = (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https://' : 'http://'); </script>"}
```

Comment: What does the *complete* response look like? It's kind of key information.

Comment: What kind of request is happening here?

Comment: i cant get a complete response..because when the src goes to the destination it finds an error..I dont think that it even gets what is inside.. The response is a small json object (which is valid)

Comment: answer updated.. It would be nice if i could get that object somehow

Comment: @BlackFire27: Good deal. I've updated my answer to point you at how to move forward.

Comment: thanks, i can see it now.. so the object needs to be wrapped in a function..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve what I want without resorting to html5 or jsonp. Can I somehow still get a response with ajax?

You're not *using* ajax. You're doing JSONP (or something functionally identical).

The response from `http://www.eya.com/wordpress/register/?callback=callbackF&ver=2.5&url=` must be a valid script fragment. From your error message, it isn't. (What I get back when I try it is a 404 page, which would tend to be an invalid script.)

---

**Update:** Your response is a valid JSON object, but not a valid JavaScript fragment, because the opening `{` looks like the beginning of a block rather than the beginning of an object literal to the parser, because it doesn't appear where an expression is expected.

To make it work the way you describe (which **is** JSONP), the response must wrap that object in the call to the callback named in the URL, like this:

```
callbackF({ "userid":"24645", "token":"40A164ECA4DE4A4F", "script":"<script type='text/javascript'>var dbnwid=16211; var dbnpid=23113; var dbnwebid=19459; var dbnlayout=21; var dbncolor='#000000'; var dbntitlefontsize='14'; var dbnbgcolortype=1; var dbnheader='You might enjoy reading:'; var dbnremindercolor=2; var dbn_protocol = (('https:' == document.location.protocol) ? 'https://' : 'http://'); </script>"})
```

[More about JSONP here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP)

Comment: true.. cause i dont reveal the page. try to test the link on a simple object

Comment: so u mean to stringify the response? isnt there some onerror handler where i could still get the whole object as a string perhaps? if i got a string back would it not throw an error? and would the string be delivered to the function

Comment: @BlackFire27: No, I mean exactly what I said above: Wrap what you're currently returning in a function call (*don't* add quotes or anything). More explicitly: Output `callbackF(` (or whatever function name is in the URL, followed by `(`) prior to what you're currently sending back, output what you're currently sending back, and then add `)` to the end. Again: The link to JSONP information should help.